# Android: Gestures not Performed Well

Tags: android

I want to use `Gesture` in my application. So I've checked out this [documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html) and createad a gesture already. Then copied that gesture to my `raw` folder which is located to `res/`.

Everything is okay from here, then I impelement `OnGesturePerformedListener` as shown below:

```
if(!mLibrary.load()) {
    Log.d("Tag", "Couldn't load");
} else {
    Log.d("Tag", "Loaded");
    GestureOverlayView gesture = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gesture.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
}
```

And finally here is my listener:

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    Log.d("Tag", "Performed");
    // We want at least one prediction
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
        // We want at least some confidence in the result
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            // Show the spell
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to draw gesture nothing changes. Even `onGesturePerformed` not working. What's problem?

I'm not sure but maybe layout could cause, here it is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gestures but ``android:layout_height="0dip"``looks a bit suspicious to me. I would've guessed gesture overview should occupy the whole gesture area?

Comment: You're right, gesture overview should occupy whole gesture area. So is `layout_height` value wrong?

Comment: ``fill_parent`` for both width and height sounds a bit more logical to me at least.

Comment: It worked properly, so if you write an answer I'll accept, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to fill entire gesture area with GestureOverlayView. Changing

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Should do the trick.